# std::min fails to interpret an enumerated constant as a valid integer type (g++ 4.6.3)

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I ran into this curious error today, I'm using std::min to get the minimum of a variable value and an enumerated constant, so far, so good, but when I go to compile it, g++ gives me a compile error indicating that it cannot find a template match for the min function:

```
no matching function for call to ‘min(int&, main()::<anonymous enum>)’
```

This is a mimimal example which reproduces the error:

```
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    int actualRange=10;
    enum { DesiredRange=8 };
    int workingRange = std::min(actualRange, DesiredRange);
    return 0;
}
```

The fix is trivial, I simple use `int(DesiredRange)` as the second parameter to the min function but it surprises me that this is necessary at all, given that the enumerated type is simply an integer constant. My system info is as follows: "g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3"

Is there something incorrect in my code which has provoked this error?, is this a valid compile error?,

Comment: Parameters to min must be of the same type both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code is alright. template argument deduction does not do conversions <del>(except derived to base)</del>, so you get this problem with a simply defined function such as `std::min`. andrei alexandrescu once wrote [a long treatise](http://www.drdobbs.com/generic-min-and-max-redivivus/184403774) about what was required, in C++03, to make a template based `min` function as type lenient as a macro.

Comment: IIRC, derived-to-base is not performed during type deduction

Comment: Thanks for the link, I can't help but feel sometimes that such tricksy minutiae works against C++ as a working language

Comment: @AndyProwl: it seems you're right so i fixed that. but there's something there... i just remembered some old code, now i need to find out what it really was about. ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Oh, wait, now I'm confused. 14.8.2.1/4: "*If P is a class and P has the form simple-template-id, then the transformed A can be a derived class of
the deduced A. Likewise, if P is a pointer to a class of the form simple-template-id, the transformed A
can be a pointer to a derived class pointed to by the deduced A*"

Answer (score 2):

What you're forgetting is that `std::min` is templated on only one type, and when you pass two different types (your enum and int) into it, the compiler can't figure out which of the two types to use and the template type, thus it fails type deduction with an error.

You could specify `std::min<int>(actualRange, DesiredRange);` if you find that clearer than your int cast mechanism.